# how to delete specific words in a line with awk?

Tags: awk

I have a text file as shown below. I need only PDB IDs after the > symbol. How can I do this with awk?

```
>results for sequence "files/1H8U.pdb" starting "ASPILEGLUGLY"
DIEGREKQQPSRVS
>results for sequence "files/1P6K.pdb" starting "ILEALALYSASP"
IAKDVAKEGSDGATKQRTHPQDSASI
```

Desired output

```
>1H8U
DIEGREKQQPSRVS
>1P6K
IAKDVAKEGSDGATKQRTHPQDSASI
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use `sed` for this, but here's the `awk`:

```
awk '/^>/ { sub (/[^\/]+\//,">", $0); sub (/\..+/, "", $0) }1' file.txt
```

Here's the `sed`:

```
sed -r '/^>/s%[^/]+/%>%;s%\..+%%' file.txt
```

Comment: N.B. In the sed solution the second substitution will be executed on each line as only the first substitution has an address. Perhaps what was intended was `sed -r '/^>/!b;s%[^/]+/%>%;s%\..+%%' file.txt` or `sed -r '/^>/{s%[^/]+/%>%;s%\..+%%}' file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
awk -F[/.] '/^>/{$1=">"$2;NF=1};1' file
```

or:

```
sed '/^>.*\/\([^.]*\)\..*/s//>\1/' file
```